# How to solve "Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor."

Tags: java, android-room

I was developing some Room simple app, where I try to keep info regarding an user, and I'm getting the following error when build the app:

> Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have
> an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the
> fields (by name and type).

This error rise in my 2 models class which are the following:

User.java

```java
@Entity(tableName = "user")
public class User {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long employee_id = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name="agency_id")
    private String agency_id = "";

    @ColumnInfo(name="user_id")
    private String user_id = "";

    @ColumnInfo(name="row_id")
    private String row_id = "";

    @ColumnInfo(name="csc_card_number")
    private String csc_card_number = "";

    @ColumnInfo(name="create_date")
    private String create_date = "";

    @ColumnInfo(name = "surname2")
    public String surname2 = "";

    @ColumnInfo(name = "surname1")
    public String surname1 = "";

    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_name")
    public String user_name = "";

    public User(long employee_id, String agency_id, String user_id, String row_id, String csc_card_number, String create_date, String surname2, String surname1, String user_name) {
        this.employee_id = employee_id;
        this.agency_id = agency_id;
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.row_id = row_id;
        this.csc_card_number = csc_card_number;
        this.create_date = create_date;
        this.surname2 = surname2;
        this.surname1 = surname1;
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }

    //Empty constructor
    public User(){

    }

    public long getEmployee_id() {
        return employee_id;
    }

    public void setEmployee_id(long employee_id) {
        this.employee_id = employee_id;
    }

    public String getAgency_id() {
        return agency_id;
    }

    public void setAgency_id(String agency_id) {
        this.agency_id = agency_id;
    }

    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getRow_id() {
        return row_id;
    }

    public void setRow_id(String row_id) {
        this.row_id = row_id;
    }

    public String getCsc_card_number() {
        return csc_card_number;
    }

    public void setCsc_card_number(String csc_card_number) {
        this.csc_card_number = csc_card_number;
    }

    public String getCreate_date() {
        return create_date;
    }

    public void setCreate_date(String create_date) {
        this.create_date = create_date;
    }

    public String getSurname2() {
        return surname2;
    }

    public void setSurname2(String surname2) {
        this.surname2 = surname2;
    }

    public String getSurname1() {
        return surname1;
    }

    public void setSurname1(String surname1) {
        this.surname1 = surname1;
    }

    public String getUser_name() {
        return user_name;
    }

    public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }
}
```

UserAuth.java

```java
@Entity(tableName = "userAuth")
public class UserAuth {

    public UserAuth(long user_id, String rowid, long authentication_group_id, long authentication_type_id, String login, String password) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.rowid = rowid;
        this.authentication_group_id = authentication_group_id;
        this.authentication_type_id = authentication_type_id;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    //Empty constructor
    public UserAuth(){

    }

    @PrimaryKey
    private long user_id = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "rowid")
    private String rowid = "";

    @ColumnInfo(name = "authentication_group_id")
    private long authentication_group_id = 0;

    @ColumnInfo (name = "auhentication_type_id")
    private long authentication_type_id = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "login")
    private String login = "";

    @ColumnInfo(name = "password")
    private String password = "";

    public long getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(long user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getRowid() {
        return rowid;
    }

    public void setRowid(String rowid) {
        this.rowid = rowid;
    }

    public long getAuthentication_group_id() {
        return authentication_group_id;
    }

    public void setAuthentication_group_id(long authentication_group_id) {
        this.authentication_group_id = authentication_group_id;
    }

    public long getAuthentication_type_id() {
        return authentication_type_id;
    }

    public void setAuthentication_type_id(long authentication_type_id) {
        this.authentication_type_id = authentication_type_id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Regarding my Database class is this:

pkg_users

```java
@androidx.room.Database(
        entities = {
                User.class,
                UserAuth.class
        },
        version = 6
)

@TypeConverters({DateConverter.class})
public abstract class pkg_users extends RoomDatabase {

    public static pkg_users buildDataBase(final Context context){
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
                context,
                pkg_users.class,
                AppConstant.PKG_USERS_DB)
                .allowMainThreadQueries().setJournalMode(RoomDatabase.JournalMode.TRUNCATE)
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
    }

    public abstract UserDao userUiContractDaoDAO();


}
```

And my DAO is this:

```java
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

    //User queries
    @Insert
    void insert(User userUi);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    LiveData<List<User>> getUserList();

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user")
    LiveData<List<Long>> getIds();

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT agency_id FROM user")
    LiveData<List<String>> getAgencyIds();

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user")
    LiveData<List<String>> getUserIds();

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT user_name FROM user")
    LiveData<List<String>> getUserNames();

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT surname1 FROM user")
    LiveData<List<String>> getSurname1();

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT surname2 FROM user")
    LiveData<List<String> >getSurname2();

    @Query("SELECT create_date FROM user WHERE user_id =:user_id")
    LiveData<String> getCreatedDateByUserId(String user_id);

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE agency_id=:agency_id")
    LiveData<Integer> getCountByAgencyId(int agency_id);

    //UserAuth queries

    @Insert
    void insertAuth(UserAuth userAuth);
    @Query("SELECT user_id FROM userAuth")
    LiveData<List<String>> getUsersAuthIds();

    @Query("SELECT login FROM userAuth WHERE user_id=:user_id")
    LiveData<String> getLoginByUserId(String user_id);

    @Query("SELECT password FROM userAuth WHERE user_id=:user_id")
    LiveData<String> getPasswordByUserId(String user_id);

    @Query("SELECT authentication_group_id FROM userAuth WHERE user_id=:user_id")
    LiveData<String> getAuthenticationGroupIdByUserId(String user_id);

    @Query("SELECT auhentication_type_id FROM userAuth WHERE user_id=:user_id")
    LiveData<String> getAuthenticationTypeIdBuUserId(String user_id);
}
```

I was looking for some forums, seeing this error can be generate by multiple causes. So I tried some solutions which don't work:

- Initialize the attribute of models.
- Fix getters and setters to match the names of models attributes.
- Generate empty constructor in models.

Also I see that some notations like @Ignore can cause this trouble, but it's not my case.

So, what am I missing, how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:-

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user")
LiveData<long[]> getIds();

@Query("SELECT user_id FROM userAuth")
LiveData<long[]> getUsersAuthIds();

@Query("SELECT authentication_group_id FROM userAuth WHERE user_id=:user_id")
LiveData<Long> getAuthenticationGroupIdByUserId(String user_id);

@Query("SELECT auhentication_type_id FROM userAuth WHERE user_id=:user_id")
LiveData<Long> getAuthenticationTypeIdBuUserId(String user_id);
```

P.S. using `@Ignore` on the full constructors will reduce the warnings issued re multiple constructors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually it's a working solution, but finally I've solved it by another way